# Can I match on different parts of an expression in a switch case?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch-statement to match a part of a string to different values.

My problem is that the part of string that I need to match varies in length, the example below is depicting what I am trying to do.

```
String s = "ABC";

switch(s) {
    case s.substring(0,1).equals("A"):
        //Do something
        break;
    case s.substring(0,2).equals("AB"):
        //Do something else
        break;
    default:
        //Do something other than else
        break;
}
```

I've tried to use `java.util.regex` but can't really figure out how to implement it..

Bonus question: Would it be better to just use a sequence of if statements? I want to be able to expand the conditions easily and effectively.

Comment: if you want to always match from start then you can do String.startWith() there are numerous ways to do it but I think keep it simple with if else. Also make sure your order and precedence of execution is right

Comment: better to use regex. That will be simple and efficient

Comment: You can't do this with a switch-statment.

Comment: Be aware that in your example the second condition will never be evaluated to true because "AB" will always match with the first check. I also think a series of if statements will do just fine. Maybe at some point you want to execute "all matching" and than a switch is much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String#matches` here with if-else logic:

```
if (s.matches("ABC.*")) {
    // do something
{
else if (s.matches("AB.*")) {
    // do something else
}
else if (s.matches("A.*")) {
    // do something else
}
else {
    // no match
}
```

Note that we check for the more specific match first, and then fallback to capturing less specific matches.  If we checked in the reverse order, then both `ABC` and `ABD` would be caught with the starts with `A` logic, and the more specific matches would not happen.

Comment: Right, your note is very true. thanks!
So in the long run I don't lose anything by using an if-else statement here instead of a case?

Comment: @shurda Under the hood, Java's `case` statement is probably implemented using `if` and `else`.  No, there is nothing wrong with if else here, other than that we lose the syntactic sugar which `case` brings to the table.